# SQL Syntax '="'||Name||'"' ( How does this work)

Tags: sql

```
select 
  '="'||SSN||'"' as SSN,
   GROUP_ID,
  '="'||GROUP_NUM||'"' as GROUP_NUM from DEPT
```

Please explain '="'||SSN||'"' ? How does this work?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with it to find out what it does? Maybe even reading the documentation? You should.

Comment: `||` is the SQL *string concatenation operator*, in other languages that's `+`, `&`, `&&`, `.` or some other character, depending on the language.

Answer (score 2):

|| is a string concatination operator, and the single quotes are string delimiters, so `'="'||SSN||'"'` concatinates `="` with the value of SSN and then with `"` so you will end up with a string that looks something like `="000-00-0000"` where 000-00-0000 is the value of SSN

Answer (score 1):

This returns the following string as value for the 1st column in the return set:

="SSN"

where SSN is replaced by the value of column SSN in the DB.
The double pipe || is used to concatenate different values or strings.

Comment: why not just select ssn from dept

Comment: To use the return set and put it in a file or display it in an nice way or ...